# Can copy/move ctors be safely used to implement copy/move assignment operators?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, constructor, idioms

I think the following code is better than copy-and-swap idiom.

In this way, you can use two macros to encapsulate the definitions of copy and move assignment operator. In other words, you can avoid to explicitly define them in your code. As a consequence, you can focus your attention on ctors and dtor only.

Is there any disadvantage of the method?

```
class A
{
public:
    A() noexcept
        : _buf(new char[128])
    {}

    ~A() noexcept
    {
        if (_buf)
        {
            delete[] _buf;
            _buf = nullptr;
        }
    }

    A(const A& other) noexcept
        : A()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
        {
            _buf[i] = other._buf[i];
        }
    }

    A(A&& other) noexcept
        : _buf(other._buf)
    {
        _buf = nullptr;
    }

    A& operator =(const A& other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            this->~A();
            new(this) A(other);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    A& operator =(A&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            this->~A();
            new(this) A(static_cast<A&&>(other));
        }

        return *this;
    }

private:
    char* _buf;
};
```

Comment: How exactly is your default constructor `noexcept`? And your move constructor doesn't move anything. There's no need to check for `nullptr` before `delete`ing something. And why `static_cast<A&&>` instead of `std::move`?

Comment: _buf(other._buf) and other._buf = nullptr; are just the move operation.

Comment: `static_cast<A&&>` can be used in some environments where the standard library cannot be used. So it is more compatible than `std::move`.

Comment: You're in trouble if the copy or move constructor can throw an exception.

Comment: It *would've been* the move operation if you'd actually written `other._buf = nullptr;`. And as Kerrek commented above, neither of your assignment operators offer a strong exception guarantee, while copy & swap does.

Comment: @Praetorian Both assignment operators provide the strongest possible exception guarantee - they are marked `noexcept` so they "cannot fail."

Comment: @Casey But the `noexcept` is bogus for the copy assignment operator, it calls the copy constructor, which in turn delegates to the default constructor, which has a `new` in it, but is yet somehow magically `noexcept`. I suppose it's fine to lie about `noexcept` if you don't mind your program terminating when you violate that guarantee.

Comment: @Praetorian `noexcept` doesn't mean "nothing in this function can throw exceptions." It means "No exceptions will ever be emitted from this function." The `noexcept` guarantee is a characteristic of the interface to a function, much like the return type. It is notably not a constraint on how that function is implemented. I'm arguing semantics, and I'm aware that you personally understand this. But I feel it's important to make the distinction clear to the programmers out there who believe that `noexcept` is something the compiler validates against the implementation like `const`. </soapbox>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A
{
public:
    A() noexcept
        : _buf(new char[128])
    {}
```

In the above, `A()` will call `std::terminate()` if `new char[128]` throws an exception.

```
    ~A() noexcept
    {
        if (_buf)
        {
            delete[] _buf;
            _buf = nullptr;
        }
    }
```

In the above, looks ok.  Could be simplified down to:

```
    ~A() noexcept
    {
        delete[] _buf;
    }



    A(const A& other) noexcept
        : A()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
        {
            _buf[i] = other._buf[i];
        }
    }
```

In the above, will call `std::terminate()` if `new char[128]` throws an exception.  But otherwise fine.

```
    A(A&& other) noexcept
        : _buf(other._buf)
    {
        _buf = nullptr;
    }
```

In the above, looks good.

```
    A& operator =(const A& other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            this->~A();
            new(this) A(other);
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

In the above, normally I'd say this is dangerous.  What if `new(this) A(other);` throws?  In this case, it won't, because if it tries to, the program will terminate.  Whether that is safe behavior or not depends on the application (terminate didn't work well for Ariane 5, but works fine in more mundane applications).

```
    A& operator =(A&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            this->~A();
            new(this) A(static_cast<A&&>(other));
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

The above should work fine.  Though I'm not sure it is superior to this non-branching version below with otherwise equivalent performance.  A behavioral difference is that the version below is not a no-op for self-move-assignment.  However it is my belief that self-move-assignment need not be a no-op as one of the post conditions state that the resulting value is unspecified (the other post-condition states that it is specified, leading to a undependable contradiction).

```
    A& operator =(A&& other) noexcept
    {
        delete [] _buf;
        _buf = nullptr;
        _buf = other._buf;
        other._buf = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work correctly in the context you provided.

This technique will be disastrous when A is a polymorphic class and has virtual destructor.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Imagine, A is a "non-final" data class, say, a shape keeping brush and color. And class B derived from A is a specialized shape (e.g. a circle). Then the code `B b(...);` and later `b = A(...)` was intended to brush and color of `b` but instead is calling its destructor (because destructor is a _virtual_ function). What is worse, the line `new(this) A` will replace virtual table pointer of B to virtual table pointer of A, and that will lead to hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You could *greatly* simplify this class by using `unique_ptr<char[]>` for `_buf`:

```
class A
{
public:
    static const std::size_t bufsize = 128;
    
    A() noexcept
        : _buf(new char[bufsize])
    {}

    A(const A& other) noexcept
        : A()
    {
        copy_from(other);
    }

    A(A&& other) noexcept = default;

    A& operator =(const A& other) noexcept
    {
        copy_from(other);
        return *this;
    }

    A& operator =(A&& other) noexcept = default;

private:
    void copy_from(const A& other) noexcept {
        std::copy_n(other._buf.get(), bufsize, _buf.get());
    }

    std::unique_ptr<char[]> _buf;
};
```

The class is shorter, more idiomatic, and safer in the face of future changes since it avoids the "clever" `delete` + placement `new`. I personally would remove the `noexcept` from `A()` and `A(const A&)`, but if you want the program to `terminate` on allocation failure that's your choice ;)

If your goal is simply to avoid writing assignment operators - and I don't blame you, they're annoyingly banal - you should design to the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/):

```
class A
{
public:
    static const std::size_t bufsize = 128;
    
    A() : _buf(bufsize) {}

private:
    std::vector<char> _buf;
};
```

There - all implicit copies and moves.

Comment: +1 this is the right way to do this, and the second version should be preferred unless you absolutely cannot afford the few extra bytes of storage a `vector` will cost you.